# mule all message router

Tags: mule, mule-studio

When ALL message router is used, what happens to the response from the endpoints. Usually when we send a message to a single synchronous endpoint it receives the response and passes it to the next step. However, if we use all and there are multiple synchronous endpoints what happens ?

```
<all>
  <jms:endpoint queue="test.queue" transformer-refs="StringToJmsMessage"/>
  <http:endpoint host="10.192.111.11" transformer-refs="StringToHttpClientRequest"/>
  <tcp:endpoint host="10.192.111.12" transformer-refs="StringToByteArray"/>
</all>
```

Can I also call subflows using all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-All):

> All messages (if any) returned by the targets are aggregated together and form the response from this processor.

And yes, you can use `flow-ref`s in `all`.